# What datastructure to use for finding the intersection of 2 trees

Tags: java, search, data-structures, hashmap, equals

I have two tree, which contains nodes, after I've created them, I take all the nodes of the first tree to a linkedlist, and the second ones to a hashmap, as the keys of the map. I would like to find two nodes from the trees, which has the same variable called: states (long type). So after the creation I call:

```
List<Node> list;
HashMap<Node, Node> hashtable;

...create nodes, take them to the collections

for(Node n : list){
    if(hashtable.containsKey(n)){
        //doSomething          
    }
}
```

I'm using hashmap, because it is very fast, though I have 4000000 (4 million) nodes. I've overridden the equals method of the Node class, but seems like the containskey method checks the hashcodes, however as far as I understood it only has to check the equals method [link to java reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29). So the question is what datastructure should I use, to check this thing, or how should i rewrite the code?

Here's my equals method:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof Node){
        Node node = (Node)obj;
        return (states == node.getStates());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override `hashCode()` method when overriding `equals()` so that equal objects must have the same hash code. Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object).

Comment: i use the parent, and the state variables of the nodes, to create the hashes, and then they are unique, if i only use the state variable, then there are a lot of node with the same state, so i have about 50000 node in the hashmap instead of 2 million. but still i want to nodes to be equal if their states are equal.

Comment: i mean i'd like to use the hashes only to sort the nodes in the map

Comment: This does not cancel the requirement about conformance with ``equal()`` and ``hashCode()``. So you have two trees of ``Node`` and want to find the intersection. For this I suggest you using great Apache utils. See [link](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#intersection(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection))

Comment: do you think it's quick enough to compare this big data?

Comment: At least you can try. Think it's quite fast.